# 401 Unauthorized on JQuery.ajax GET request in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm getting "401 unauthorized" for the below ajax call,

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: url1,
                headers: { "Authorization": "Basic Auth"},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                timeout: 190000,
                success: response3 });
```

So I tried creating the same using XMLHttpRequest as below,

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
method = "GET";
xhr.open(method, url1, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic Auth");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
  response3(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

and it is working fine. 
What's the issue in JQuery.ajax? and why it is working fine using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the method on your request? `method: 'GET'`

Comment: @l.g.karolos `type` does the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried using `beforeSend` instead of `headers`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax